# A conditional render of an icon does not get re-rendered even though there was a successful edit to the database triggered by an onPress()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I cannot get my component to re-render the correct icon even though the onPress() fired successfully -- in editing an array in the database.

In one view, I have a FlatList which shows individual cards. In the card, I have a coloured-icon which I want to re-render as an outlined-icon when the icon is pressed, and vice versa. I am not using useState because the change is to an array in a remote database (Firebase Firestore).

My code successfully achieved this in the FlatList view. But not in the detailed item view. I do not understand why it works in one view and not the other.

When I navigate to a detailed item view of each card, which also shows the same pressable icon for the card, I am able to press the icon and fire the onPress() successfully, but the icon does not re-render unless the view is manually refreshed -- by navigating back and forth.

Here is my code:

```
const CauseDetailScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { data } = route.params

  const handleVote = async (id, owner_email) => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", owner_email, "MyCollection", id)

    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

    if (docSnap.data().votes_by_users.includes(auth.currentUser.email)) {
      // un-vote
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        votes_by_users: arrayRemove(auth.currentUser.email),
      })
    } else {
      // user vote
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        votes_by_users: arrayUnion(auth.currentUser.email),
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ width: "100%", height: 373 }}>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: data.image }}
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
    />
    <CircleButton
      imgUrl={assets.left}
      handlePress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      left={15}
      top={StatusBar.currentHeight + 10}
    />
    <View
      style={{
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        flexDirection: "row",
      }}
    >
      <Chip icon="vote" selectedColor="#000">
        {data.votes_by_users.length}
      </Chip>

      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          handleVote(data.id, data.owner_email)
        }}
        icon={() =>
          data.votes_by_users.includes(auth.currentUser.email) ? (
            <Image
              source={require("../res/healing.png")}
              style={{
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            />
          ) : (
            <Image
              source={require("../res/healing-outline.png")}
              style={{
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    </View>
    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
      <CauseTitle data={data} />
      <CauseDescription data={data} />
    </View>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

)
}

```
export default CauseDetailScreen
```

Here is the screenshot examples, showing that the conditionally rendering of the icon works in the FlatList view but does not work in the detailed item view.

[FlatList view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TJ4k.png)

[Flatlist view re-render the correct icon after pressed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1yFs.png)

[Detailed item view does not re-render the correct icon after successful pressed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJZgb.png)

Update:

I've tried removing the image from the icon prop but the same issue still persists.

My code:

```
<View>
        {data.votes_by_users.includes(auth.currentUser.email) ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              handleVote(data.id, data.owner_email)
            }}
          >
            <Image
              source={require("../res/healing.png")}
              style={{
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              handleVote(data.id, data.owner_email)
            }}
          >
            <Image
              source={require("../res/healing-outline.png")}
              style={{
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
```

Update:

Someone suggested that I need to reset data that I got from the route.params, this kind of make sense but I don't understand enough to resolve this. How should I reset data from route.params?